# timestamp countdown going in negative

Tags: javascript

I have a script that countdowns timestamp. It is working fine but the problem it keeps going less than 0 into negative. I want it to stop at zero.

```js
// $nowtime is a date in future
var startLive = new Date("<?php echo $nowtime; ?>");
var timestamp = startLive - Date.now();

timestamp /= 1000; // from ms to seconds

function component(x, v) {
  return Math.floor(x / v);
}

var $div = $('.time');

timer = setInterval(function() {

  timestamp--;

  var days = component(timestamp, 24 * 60 * 60),
    hours = component(timestamp, 60 * 60) % 24,
    minutes = component(timestamp, 60) % 60,
    seconds = component(timestamp, 1) % 60;

  $div.html(days + " days, " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);


}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

> Output looks like 1 Days, 6:10:30

Problem is if it is less than zero it still goes in negative. something like **-3 days, -3:-5:-5**

How to stop at 0.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
timer = setInterval(function() {

    /* if timestamp <= 0 return means skip rest of function */
    if(timestamp <= 0) {
        clearInterval(timer); 
        return;
    }

    timestamp--;

    var days    = component(timestamp, 24 * 60 * 60),
        hours   = component(timestamp,      60 * 60) % 24,
        minutes = component(timestamp,           60) % 60,
        seconds = component(timestamp,            1) % 60;

    $div.html(days + " days, " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);


}, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks. Working. I tried on my own but forgot about return :)

Comment: Actually, you should clear the interval with `clearInterval(timer); ` instead of only returning, otherwise the interval will still be called on the background.
If you add a `console.log('something')` inside your if statement and before the return you will see that the interval is still being called.

Comment: @CarlaBabadopulos very true! thank you, updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(timestamp <= 0)
{
clearInterval(timer); 
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!